# Suggestions for drawing a bar as shown below

Tags: html, html5-canvas

depending on the value, we need to draw bars as shown below. What do you suggest? canvas, svg or some charting tools?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use plain old `<div>` elements? You can set the length of the bar by using CSS width as a percentage, with a fixed size parent element this should give you what you need. Example below, restyle as required:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 20px;">
            <div style="width: 30%; height: 18px; background-color: red"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```